# Is it possible to "unprocess" a cube in SSAS to retrieve only the metadata?

Tags: metadata, ssas, cube, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

I would like to know if it's possible to "unprocess" a cube in SSAS. I want to do this so I can perform a "synchronization" between two differents servers. This (I think), will remove all the data and left the metadata to be synchronized? Am I right?

Do you know a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the ability to unprocess, although that'd leave your cube unprocessed. Right-click database, select process, in the next window change process type to Unprocess and "Script to new window" in top-right.

If you just want a schema though, can you not script the "Script Database as Create" XMLA? Then drop your target and run the Create XMLA against the target server?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Am I right to think that "unprocess" the cube will only left the structure and no data at all? In fact, "Script Database..." works but I want to make this action automatic. I already scripted the synchronize part. Just that the data must not follow the synchronization (e.g to synchronize the structure from DEV to PROD environment)

Comment: @el_grom Yes, just process "Unprocess" and you should be left with the empty cubes: Drops the data in the object specified and any lower-level constituent objects. After the data is dropped, it is not reloaded. This processing option is supported for cubes, databases, dimensions, measure groups, mining models, mining structures, and partitions. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174774(v=sql.100).aspx )